# Allow Camel to start up even if the "from" endpoint is currently not available

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a camel application running with Spring Boot. I want to improve resilience by letting my application start up even if one or more of the "from" endpoints (MQ or SMPP in my case) are not currently available - I want the application to just keep checking, and pick up messages once the endpoint becomes available.

Current code:

```java
// Application.java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application 
{   
    @Autowired private CamelContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
   @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(ProducerTemplate template) 
    {
        return args -> 
        {
            context.addRoutes(new MQRouteBuilder());
            context.addRoutes(new SMPPRouteBuilder());
        };
    }
}

// example route builder
public class SMPPRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
{
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        from("smpp://{{camel.component.smpp.configuration.host}}").to("direct:processSMS");
        //...
    }
}
```

Currently, if the SMS-C defined as camel.component.smpp.configuration.host isn't available, the application fails to start:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> Application.main(Application.java:28)
> ~[classes/:na] Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
> java.io.IOException: localhostInvalid     at
> org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(RuntimeCamelException.java:68)
> ~[camel-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:134)
> ~[camel-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:2989)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(AbstractCamelContext.java:3327)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(AbstractCamelContext.java:3258)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3163)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3189)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startRouteService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3033)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.start(DefaultModel.java:358)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRoute(DefaultModel.java:330)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:323)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.addRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:88)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.AbstractModelCamelContext.addRouteDefinitions(AbstractModelCamelContext.java:110)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.populateRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:520)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:437)
> ~[camel-core-engine-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.lambda$addRoutes$0(AbstractCamelContext.java:1160)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(AbstractCamelContext.java:2544)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:1160)
> ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> Application.lambda$0(Application.java:42)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    ... 5 common frames
> omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: localhostInvalid  at
> org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppConnectionFactory.createConnection(SmppConnectionFactory.java:112)
> ~[camel-smpp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.connectAndBind(SMPPSession.java:222)
> ~[jsmpp-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.connectAndBind(SMPPSession.java:201)
> ~[jsmpp-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
> org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppConsumer.createSession(SmppConsumer.java:95)
> ~[camel-smpp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppConsumer.doStart(SmppConsumer.java:84)
> ~[camel-smpp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]     at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
> ~[camel-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]  ... 23 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: localhostInvalid   at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.apache.camel.component.smpp.SmppConnectionFactory.createConnection(SmppConnectionFactory.java:99)
> ~[camel-smpp-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

What I want instead, is for the application to start up, start listening on the connections it can connect to (e.g. MQ), and just periodically retry the ones it can't until they become available.

Comment: Simon, what tool did u use to test if smsc was up? did u use telnet?

Comment: Not specifically, I just configured the camel route and the camel route tries to connect. If it fails to connect, then it knows it's not up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but with JMS component.

Here is what I did:

1. Set an id on my route (`.routeId("demo")`)
2. Put my route with `.autostart(false)`
3. Add to the context an **extra** system-oriented route with a `from("timer:")` in order to regularly monitor the health of (in my case) the JMS broker. When the broker is detected "up", then a Camel processor can simply (via Camel API) ask te controller to restart the involved route(s): `context.getRouteController().start("demo")`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. What sort of code can you use to detect if the broker is up? Is it something standard in Camel or did you use custom code?

Comment: What I usually do is to issue a `telnet` on the target IP+port, and assume the server is up if telnet response is successful. There are many opensource java libs to run telnet like commands.

Comment: You could also probably use camel-mina or camel-netty (never tried) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `autoStartup=false` that, however will not re-connect later when working. As the name implies the route is not started, and you need to do that manually later.

You can also take a look at supervised route controller, that can re-start failing routes on startup.

- https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html#_supervisingroutecontroller